# How can I create a odbc layer on top of existing business data?

Tags: c#, c++, sql, database, odbc

I want to expose our internal bussiness data through odbc driver. One of the propitary product that i found is [DataDirect](http://web.datadirect.com/) OpenAccess. I want to use SQL to query live data from our data source. Writing my own SQLEngine will take ages but i need something like following diagram. We intend to use it on live data so exporting it to database and than running query is not a good solution at this time.  Can anyone guide me how can i solve it using opensource.

[link text http://web.datadirect.com/images/products/custom-driver-sdk/OpenAccess-SDK.jpg](http://web.datadirect.com/images/products/custom-driver-sdk/OpenAccess-SDK.jpg)

Comment: Where is the live data stored now? Is it stored as individual files on disk? binary, text?

Comment: Actually live data is on Lisp engine. It can be persisted to disk but format in which is stored is only readable by the application. Now we like end user to use SQL to query data on Lisp which can be projected as tables/columns/rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements you describe, I don't see any choice but for you to develop an odbc driver that knows how to talk to your lisp engine.  This will be a non-trivial task.

However, since you mention open source, you may be able to get a running start by looking at one of the the open source odbc drivers such as iODBC.

Answer (score 1):

Affan,
A solution widely used in the Open Source world (Hadoop, Cassandra etc.) is the SimbaEngine SDK.
You can build a fully SQL complaint ODBC Driver in 5 Days. No need to write your own SQLEngine as it is baked in already. Download it from here, its free   www.simba.com

Cheers,
Tom